# Excel - VBA: formatNumber for date (yyyy-mm-dd) not working with all values

Tags: excel, date, formatting, vba

I'm using VBA to generate a XLS sheet based on other sheets from the same XLS file.
It's pretty basic and all works except the following:

```
varSheetGeneratedCSV.Range("E" & j).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd;@"
varSheetGeneratedCSV.Range("F" & j).NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd;@"
```

The value I pass are selected from a sheet's cells which are formatted with the following format:

- Custom: aaaa/mm/jj (French locale, equivalent to yyyy/mm/dd)

The sheets gets the expected value in the cells (j is a loop index) for both E and F columns.

But here are my results, depending on something I can't pin point, can you ?

Input:

- Start: 2011/12/01
- End: 2037/12/31

Result:

- 2011/12/01 (expected)
- 31/12/2037 (not expected, expected: 2037/12/31)

---

Input:

- Start: 2028/06/19
- End: 2018/12/9

Result:

- 19/06/2028 (not expected, expected: 2028/06/19)
- 19/12/2018 (not expected, expected: 2018/12/19)

---

Any idea why the difference ?
Note that when I double click the cell not correctly format and, without doing any change, hit enter, the format is then applied correctly.

What could I add to my VBA to get the cell format to be applied as when I do it manually ?

Thank you!

Comment: Are your input values stored as dates or as text?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that actually enters the information into the cells

Comment: The input values are in cells formatted with Date "aaaa/mm/jj" (equivalent to "yyyy/mm/dd")
I specify "yyyy/mm/dd" as format in VBA 

Users need to input the dates with the same format, and I want the cells in which I copy the values to remain but they change. Not all the time as detailed in the post

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by generating the date via date functions:

```
varSheetGeneratedCSV.Range("E" & j) = Year(varStartDate) & "/" & Month(varStartDate) & "/" & Day(varStartDate)
```

This outputs the correct value each time.